# Why can't Python struct module pack (or unpack) multi bytes with little endian

Tags: python, struct, byte, endianness, pack

I'm dealing with some multi bytes issues. For example, I have a variable `a = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03'`, it is a `bytes` object rather than `int`. I'd like to `struct.pack` it to form a package with **little endian**, but `<4s` didn't work. In fact, `<4s` and `>4s` get the same results. What to do if I'd like the result to be `b'\x03\x02\x01\x00`.
I know I could use `struct.pack('<L', struct.unpack('>L', a))`, but is it the **only** and **correct** way to deal with multi bytes objects?

Example:

```py
import struct
import secrets

mhdr = b'\x20'
joineui = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07'
deveui = b'\x08\x09\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15'
devnonce = secrets.token_bytes(2)

joinreq = struct.pack(
    '<s8s8s2s',
    mhdr,
    joineui,
    deveui,
    devnonce,
)

# The expected joinreq should be b'\x20\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01\x00\x15\x14\x13\x12\x11\x10\x09\x08...'
```

Comment: `4s` means four individual bytes. Endiannes only applies to multi-byte values, so it does not affect how you read strings.

Comment: @jdehesa No, `4s` means one `bytes` object of 4 byte-length, not four individual bytes.

Comment: Yes, but I mean that the "object" is made of four individual bytes. If you had `4i` it would be four individual integers, and you could change the endianness of each integer, but the first integer would always be first, then second, etc. For your case, you may just reverse the byte strings, since there is only one "object" on each (`joineui[::-1]`, `deveui[::-1]`).

Comment: @jdehesa That works, but I need to reverse them in several parts of the program, I also need to `unpack` data back from servers where I have to do these `[::-1]` over several multi-byte fields. This feels bad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you do not want to have 4 single chars, but instead 1 integer.
So instead of '4s' you should try using 'i' or 'I' (whether it is signed or unsigned).

Your example should look like

```
import struct
import secrets

mhdr = b'\x20'
joineui = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07'
deveui = b'\x08\x09\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15'
devnonce = secrets.token_bytes(2)

joinreq = struct.pack(
    '<BQQH', #use small letters if the values are signed instead of unsigned
    mhdr,
    joineui,
    deveui,
    devnonce,
)
```

"Q" stands for long long unsigned (8byte). If you want to use float instead you can use d for double float precision (8byte).

You can see the meaning of all letters in [the documentation of struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Comment: It couldn't work directly, because if I use `QQHB`, the following arguments must be four integers but not four `bytes`. So I have to unpack all `bytes` objects to integers first, as I've explained in my question.